# Parsing JSON array in Azure Logic App from base64 encoded string to use in For_each

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, string-interpolation, azure-servicebus-queues, workflow-definition-language

I am trying to iterate through a `JSON` array which has been encoded to a string for the purpose of storing on a queue. However, I receive the following error message:

> {"code":"ExpressionEvaluationFailed","message":"The execution of
>   template action 'For_each' failed: The result '[{\"Foo\":\"Bar\"}]' of
>   the evaluation of 'foreach' action expression
>   '@{json(decodeBase64(triggerBody()['ContentData']))}' is not a valid
>   array."}

The following is the string being parsed:
`[{"Foo":"Bar"}]`

I have no problems parsing a `JSON` string when it is not in an array, for example:
`{"Foo":"Bar"}`

This parses just fine when I am not using a `For_each`.

How do I get the logic app to read this as an array?

Comment: I'd try to test array representation in the form of { [{"Foo":"Bar"}] }

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using string interpolation (where expressions are wrapped in @{ ... }) that evaluates to a string representation of the array. Hence evaluation of the 'foreach' expression fails.

You want the expression to be
`@json(decodeBase64(triggerBody()['ContentData']))`

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thank you Szymon. I stumbles upon the error while I was trying to use an azure function to return a json array. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
 json(decodeBase64(body('HTTP')?['$Content']))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLKwZ.png)